# How to add rowStyle for alternative rows in "material-table"?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-table

[I want to apply rowstyles alternative rows in material-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5F5g.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are referring to this [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/styling), if so then you can use `rowStyle`.

```
<MaterialTable
      title="Row Styling Preview"
      columns={[
        { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
        { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
        {
          title: 'Birth Place',
          field: 'birthCity',
          lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
        },
      ]}
      data={[
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
                { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
                        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
      ]}
      options={{
        rowStyle: x => {
             if (x.tableData.id % 2) {
                 return {backgroundColor: "lightgreen"}
             }
         }
      }}
    />
```

[image]

Comment: pls upvote if this answer worked for you, so that other developers also can use this code

Comment: I am unable to upvote getting this  " Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: oh ok. now you can do